# If statement inside for-loop for assigning values to dictionary in python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to assign values to a dictionary `test_dict` based on the values in an array `array_type`. Namely, I would like to assign a value of `beta` to `test_dict` in correspondence of the positions in which `array_type` is equal to 1. For this I use a for-loop with an internal if-statement.
In practice, if the value of a given element in `array_type` is 1, then assign a value of `beta` at the same position of `test_dict`.

I wrote the code below. However when I check the `counter` dictionary, which is supposed to contain the number of occurrences of 1 and 0, I do not get consistent results between the expectation and the results in the `counter`. The expectation for the `counter` results would be: `{'0' : 1000, '0.01' : 500}`.

Any advise?

```
import numpy as np
#create a 0-based array of 1500 zeros
array_type = np.zeros(1500)
#create a 1-based array with 500 elements.
vals_n = np.ones(500)
#replace 500 elements in array_type with 1.
array_type = np.insert(array_type, np.random.choice(len(array_type), size=500), vals_n)


beta = 0.01 
#initialize a counter dictionary with the two possible values
counter = {}
counter[0] = 0
counter[beta] = 0

test_dict = {}
indx = 0
for _ in range(0,1500,1):
    if array_type[indx] == 1.0:
        test_dict[indx] = beta
        counter[beta] +=1
    else:
        test_dict[indx] = 0.0
        counter[0] += 1
    indx += 1
```

Comment: This question is unclear. Please read [ask] and how to provide [mcve]. What is the result you get and what is the result you expect? Also, please explain why you expect what you expect.

Comment: I edited the question. It should be clearer. let me know if not.

Comment: are you desiring variance between when 0's occur and 1's occur? (i.e. 0's will occur at random and 1's at random but you want overall 500 1's and 1000 0's?

Comment: It can be either way. But initially I coded it thinking of maintaining the same positions as in array_type, that is, when array_type[indx] is equal to 1, give test_dict[indx] a value of beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I'll try to answer your question directly. Then I'll try to teach you something after that will simplify your code.
Change

```
array_type = np.zeros(1500)
#create a 1-based array with 500 elements.
vals_n = np.ones(500)
#replace 500 elements in array_type with 1.
array_type = np.insert(array_type, np.random.choice(len(array_type), size=500), vals_n)
```

To

```
array_type = np.zeros(1000)
#create a 1-based array with 500 elements.
vals_n = np.ones(500)
#insert randomly 500 elements in array_type with 1.
array_type = np.insert(array_type, np.random.choice(len(array_type), size=500), vals_n)
```

And your code gives your desired output... You can read up about np.insert [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-insert-python/)
Now if my job was just to give you the answer to get the counter results you wanted there it is...
I'd like to mention that test_dict is a dictionary and array_type is a numpy array... (as you were probably trying to achieve).
Instead of assigning the variable indx separately just use it directly from the for loop. Like so ->

```
for indx in range(1500):
    ...
```

No need to complicated it with an increment at the end and assignment before the loop, just use it directly, and this will increment by 1 by default. You can read up about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_for_range.asp)
Finally it appears to me that you are really trying to convert an array to a dictionary... I'm not sure how important the counter is for your use... But in other words all of your code converting from array_type to test_dict could be written as

```
test_dict = dict(enumerate(map(lambda x: beta if x==1 else 0, array_type)))
```

No need to complicate the entire process. You can see an example of this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-numpy-array-to-dictionary-in-python/#) and [here](https://realpython.com/python-map-function/) for further explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear answer and explanation. Really useful. However, I really need to keep the dictionary test_dict and the numpy array array_type distinct. Just to be clear, my objective is not to convert an array to dictionary, but rather assign a beta value in the dictionary at the exact same positions where array_type is 1.

Comment: @CafféSospeso what do you mean by distinct? I'll update my answer to include how you would do this with your beta example (if that's what you are worried about)... Because you can just use a map to map the numpy array to include the beta then convert it to dict...

Comment: ok, thanks. But this is minimal example for solving an issue that i am having in a more complex code and dependencies (among consecutive lines of the code).

Comment: @CafféSospeso to be clear the first change in this answer will ensure that your counter is correct because np.insert is inserting (not replacing) the values of the ones and zeros (which means there are 2000 entries in your example) and only 1500 examples in my entry... Was there a further specific question you were wondering? If so could you update your question to reflect that?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you expect the `np.insert` call to *replace* values in the array, but that is not true. As the name suggests it *inserts* values in the array, so that after this operation your array has grown from 1500 to 2000 values. As a consequence your loop over the first 1500 values will miss some of the 1 values which happen to occur in that last chunk of 500 elements.

Depending on your real case, there are several ways to do it correctly:

- You could initially define `type_array` with just 1000 elements, so that the insertion of 500 more elements will give it the intended size:

  ```
  array_type = np.zeros(1000)   # Only 1000. The other 500 will be inserted
  ```

  Note however, that with `np.random.choice` you only generate indices in the range 0:500, so that the distribution of inserted values is not homogeneous over the new array: inserted values are less likely to end up after the 1000 index than before.
- You could really *replace* 500 entries instead of inserting them. Use `put` for that, and make sure that `random.choice` does not pick the same index more than once:

  ```
  np.put(array_type, np.random.choice(len(array_type), size=500, replace=False), vals_n)
  ```

  Note that `put` does not return the array -- it works *inplace* on the array given as first argument.

Either of these two solutions will give the expected output:

```
{0: 1000, 0.01: 500}
```